# Three tier architecture - how to pass business class (like 100 properties) to data access

Tags: c#

I'm using C# and developing a Windows Forms project.
I am using a 3 tier architecture (UI layer, Business Logic, Data Access).

I have a table named "Customer" which has around 100 fields in it.

I want to add new Customer, am assigning all these 100 fields into the Business Layer "Customer Class", then calling an "insertCustomer" method of the business layer.

Now, from the business layer, after all validations, how can I pass the whole "customer" class together into the data access layer, so that I can make the actual insert query with all field values?

Or do I need to assign each field into variables and pass these variables as parameters from the business layer to the data access layer?

Comment: Why standard approach doesn't work for you `dataAccessInstance.AddCustomer(customerInstance)`?

Comment: Data access layer should know domain model objects (business objects) and how to persist them to data base.So the answer is: you pass the business object to data layer as is

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What does your data access layer look like? Do you use NHibernate, Linq, etc.? Do you have data access objects that look almost identical to the business logic objects? Please explain.

Comment: @Jesus: This only works if those classes are defined in the data layer, or in some shared domain model component. If they are truly defined in the business logic, then the data access layer couldn't know about them.

Comment: @Christoph. So, how many models do you have in your application? I think you should keep things simple. Having more models just complicate things for no gain. IMHO shared domain model is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, shared object models is what I usually do. However, sometimes you don't have a choice because an external service interface is fixed (exposes "business logic" data contracts) and you need to make it work with your internal data structures that are aligned with your database. In that case I use http://automapper.org/.

Comment: i am using ado.net technology in data access layer.

Comment: i dont have separate business object in data access. i just want to keep it simple (only in business layer). am using simple ado.net commands in data layer. pls guide me how to pass those many business class properties together into data access.

Comment: Put your business objects in a separate library project. Reference it from the business logic project and from the data access project. Then pass the business object from business logic to data layer as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) of your "Customer class" which will be shared between your layers(data, business). 
In short, you'll have to copy the wanted data of your "Customer class" properties in the DTO, then read the DTO in the data access layer and populate your final dataaccess class with it.

Comment: I created the 3 layers as three projects.
I want to pass data from UI to BLL to DAL and back as well. some of my tables having more than 100 fields.

If i create classes for each table in BLL, that will be a mess for me as its lot of fields.
And if i created classes in BLL, i can pass from UI to BLL. But then how to pass to DAL
with out creating another model in DAL?.

Will EF work here for me?
If it works, shall i create the EDMX as a separate project? or simply in DAL?.

Please advice.

Comment: Another case is, my company has 3 out lets. Each location is having different database,
but same structure.
If i create EF, i need to select the database there na. But will it work at my another outlet, when i
compile it and run the setup at the outlet?.
The database names and paths may be different in each locations.